# Node version of my program is different than node installation

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: fs.copyFile is not a function
```

The problem is because the function was added to Node in version 8.5. I was running the LTS version when I began this project, but after I realized I needed a newer function I updated my installation of node, but the program still seems to be running an older version. This is an electron program.

When I run

```
node -v
```

I get back

```
v8.8.1
```

but inside my program, when I run code to check what version I'm running it gives me 7.9.

How can I upgrade my project so it can run a newer version of NodeJS?

Comment: @juanlumn I don't think so. OP is looking to upgrade the node that electron will use for shipping, he does have the latest node already

Comment: @Bergi that's right. I updated the post to clarify that I am using electron.

Comment: I see, sorry I've removed it.

Comment: Good news is that Node 8.9 became the LTS version today. Bad news: Electron is slightly behind (currently at [8.2.1](https://github.com/electron/electron/commit/8ebab10cb07f41acdc14b58fcfe9e65d3e392a2f)) and they [say in their FAQ](https://electron.atom.io/docs/faq/#when-will-electron-upgrade-to-latest-nodejs) that they wait a month after new Node version is released to upgrade to it.